# How to: forcing the description of a shared Url via Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I'm using https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=myUrl to share 'myUrl', how can force description of the shared link?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sharer, it's been deprecated for quite some time. Have you looked at the Social plugins - [Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) and add the OG tags like og:description which will let you share your URL with a pre-defined description.

Comment: is there any variable I can add to the url itself to force description?

Comment: The Like button is the proper way to go, but you can try and add the meta description tag to the page and see if that gets scraped properly. eg - <meta content="my awesome site" name="description">. But I don't see a way to add anything to the URL itself to force the description. One other thing to do would be to run the URL through the FB debugger tool to see what gets scraped - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug